# Transaction fails when function attempts to edit a mapping entry

Tags: solidity, remix, mapping

I am trying to create a simple contract that lets a user deposit and withdraw eth at will

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
contract DepositRefund {
    
    mapping(address => uint) public DepositedAmounts;
    
    receive() external payable{
        DepositedAmounts[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    }       
    function refund() public{
        payable(msg.sender).call{value : DepositedAmounts[msg.sender]}("");
        DepositedAmounts[msg.sender] = 0;
    }
}
```

When I try to use the refund function after depositing funds the transaction fails with this error:

```
transact to DepositRefund.refund pending ... 

transact to DepositRefund.refund errored: VM error: out of gas.

out of gas
    The transaction ran out of gas. Please increase the Gas Limit.

Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

Obviously changing the gas limit does not fix the problem, after debugging it shows that the transaction is being reverted at this line:

```
DepositedAmounts[msg.sender] = 0;
```

If I comment that part out, the refund works and transaction goes through, but it would allow infinite refund

Comment: There is an ongoing set of issues with Remix regarding gas estimate errors, apparently linked to gas refund & the JavaScript EVM. Use ganache or hardhat in the meantime, your code is fine, except maybe that it is vulnerable to rentrency attacks on the `refund` function.

Comment: Where do you deploy? rinkeby or javascript vm?

Comment: @hroussille ok then Ill use foundry. How can I fix the vulnerability? Also is there a way to make it work without a fallback/receive function? Im very new to solidity but it seems odd to me to be able to declare only one function that manages funds sent to the contract

Comment: @blockByblock js vm on remix